# nullpointerexception on Array.newInstance for passed generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I've got such method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T, K> K[] toArray(ITemplateCommand<T,K> command, List<T> templates) {
    if (null == templates) {
        return null;
    }
    K[] array = (K[]) Array.newInstance(templates.getClass().getComponentType(), templates.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < templates.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = command.buildTemplate(templates.get(i));
    }
    return array;
}
```

And I call it there

```
@Override
public TemplateResponse buildTemplateResponse(List<NotificationTemplateDetails> templates, String offset,
    String perPage, String sort, String sortOrder, int total) {
    TemplateResponse templateResponse = new TemplateResponse();
    templateResponse.setItems(ResponseUtils.<NotificationTemplateDetails, Template>toArray(new ToTemplateCommand(), templates));
    templateResponse.setTotal(total);
    templateResponse.setRequest(buildRequestInformation(offset, perPage, sort, sortOrder));
    return templateResponse;
}
```

Where `ToTemplateCommand` is an implementation of `ITemplateCommand` iterface

```
public class ToTemplateCommand implements ITemplateCommand<NotificationTemplateDetails, Template> {

    @Override
    public Template buildTemplate(NotificationTemplateDetails template) {
    ....
```

But I've `NullPointerException` on

```
K[] array = (K[]) Array.newInstance(templates.getClass().getComponentType(), templates.size());
```

line.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
....
```

But neither `command` nor `templates` parameters are null.
What's the problem?

Comment: Check if `templates.getClass()` returns null

Comment: it returns `(java.lang.Class<T>) class java.util.ArrayList`. But `componentType` returns null. So it seems cannot recognize component type

Comment: `templates.getClass().getComponentType()` should probably be `templates.getClass()` - also note that your `toArray` method is fairly easy to test so you should probably be able to isolate the problem with a unit test and fix it.

Comment: I used `display` tab in Eclipse to recognize problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType()) for `getComponentType()` it says...

> Returns the `Class` representing the component type of an
>   array.  If this class does not represent an array class this method
>   returns null.

Comment: I see. Well I decided to add additional method to `command` class called `getClassOfK` which allows me to get `K` class and instantiate it. But I am not sure about this solution. It works now though.